# r - ggplot2 scale_x_discrete does not show the values, missing values warning

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, label, axis

I have a data frame;

![temp][1]

```
First row are headers:

 LAYER, Number, Share %
 Between 100ms - 200ms , 132 , 4.66%
 Between 15ms - 30 ms , 475 , 16.8%
 Between 200ms - 300ms , 8 , 0.282%
 Between 300ms - 400ms , 1 , 0.0353%
 Between 30ms - 50 ms , 1329 , 46.9%
 Between 400ms - 500ms , 4 , 0.141%
 Between 500ms - 600ms , 2 , 0.0706%
 Between 50ms - 100ms , 863 , 30.5%
 Greater Than 600ms , 1 , 0.0353%
 Less Than 15ms , 17 , 0.6%)
```

I am drawing the bar plot of it as:

```
myplot <- ggplot(temp, aes(as.factor(temp$layer), temp$n, label = temp$yuzde)) + xlab("") + ylab("# of SDNNs") + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.6, position = "dodge") +  
theme(axis.text=element_text(size=8), axis.title = element_text(size=8,face="bold"), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + 
scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Less Than 15ms", "Betwenn 15ms - 30 ms", "Betwenn 30ms - 50 ms", "Betwenn 50ms - 100 ms","Betwenn 100ms - 200 ms", "Betwenn 200ms - 300 ms","Betwenn 300ms - 400 ms", "Betwenn 400ms - 500 ms","Betwenn 500ms - 600 ms", "Greater Than 600ms")) +
geom_label()
```

And the graphs comes as;

[image: ggplot]

but when I exclude `scale_x_discrete`, everything is normal ! 
Like this;

[ggplot normal][3]

But I want to have it as it is in the first x axis order.

So, `scale_x_discrete` ruins my plot. I tried factor and level editing also but they do not work either !

Can anybody help to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some data that we can actually use would be useful instead of a unusable picture. use `dput(temp)` and paste the result into the question

Comment: Anyhow, the bars don't show up because the strings you typed differs from tha values in the `df`.

Comment: Yes, that is my problem I asked to be solved ! Bars do not show up when you use scale_x_discrete thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to reorder the levels of the `LAYER` factor in the `df`:

```
df$LAYER <- factor(df$LAYER, levels = levels(df$LAYER)[c(10,2,5,8,1,3,4,6,7,9)])
```

Then you can simply:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = LAYER, y = Number, label = Share)) +
    geom_col() +
    geom_label() +
    theme(axis.text = element_text(size=8), 
          axis.title = element_text(size=8,face="bold"), 
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

I think it's still ugly as hell, but that's what you asked.

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'LAYER Number Share
                 "Between 100ms - 200ms" 132  4.66%
                 "Between 15ms - 30 ms"  475  16.8%
                 "Between 200ms - 300ms"  8  0.282%
                 "Between 300ms - 400ms"  1  0.0353%
                 "Between 30ms - 50 ms"  1329  46.9%
                 "Between 400ms - 500ms"  4  0.141%
                 "Between 500ms - 600ms"  2  0.0706%
                 "Between 50ms - 100ms"  863  30.5%
                 "Greater Than 600ms"  1  0.0353%
                 "Less Than 15ms"  17  0.6% ', header = T)
```